# Audit Trial of Users (which is created in Database Table )

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, logging, audit-trail

I Have a database on SQL Server 2014 with one SQL Server Login to Connection for each user but different UserID and Password in the database table to authentication for each user.

Each User have right to insert, update and delete a record 
I want to Save these transactions with userid  in separate table as Audit Trial
My Application developed on Windows Forms (Desktop App) and Web Forms (Web App)
both connected to the same database userid also same

I found  Change Data Capture (CDC) feature but not fulfill my requirement with it because I want to save transactions with userid and CDC not known userid

Comment: How is Your app connected to database? Do You run all Queries by text?

Comment: No, Use Stored Procedure (SQL) or CommandBuilder (C#)

Answer (score -1):

Use this to insert records into the table. Eventually, you can script the second query to a SP and run everyday from SQL Agent. Hope this Helps
Ven

```
Create table eventsLog

    ( 

     EventClass varchar(10)
    ,LoginName Varchar(100)
    ,SPid int
    ,Starttime date
    ,ObjectName Varchar(255)
    ,DBName varchar(100)
    ,Hostname varchar (100)

    )


    Insert into eventsLog

    SELECT e.NAME AS eventclass
        ,t.loginname
        ,t.spid
        ,t.starttime
        ,t.objectname
        ,t.databasename
        FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable(CONVERT(VARCHAR(150), (
                    SELECT TOP 1 f.[value]
                    FROM sys.fn_trace_getinfo(NULL) f
                    WHERE f.property = 2
                    )), DEFAULT) T
    INNER JOIN sys.trace_events e
        ON t.eventclass = e.trace_event_id
    WHERE eventclass = 164
```

Comment: The default trace does not record DML. What your example shows is the DDL events of "Object:Altered" class, not the "insert, update and delete", moreover, the trace loggs only a login and the OP's application connects under the same login every time